# Is unsubscribe thread safe in RxJava?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

Suppose I have the following RxJava code (which accesses a DB, but the exact use case is irrelevant):

```
public Observable<List<DbPlaceDto>> getPlaceByStringId(final List<String> stringIds) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<DbPlaceDto>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<DbPlaceDto>> subscriber) {
            try {
                Cursor c = getPlacseDb(stringIds);

                List<DbPlaceDto> dbPlaceDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    dbPlaceDtoList.add(getDbPlaceDto(c));
                }
                c.close();

                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(dbPlaceDtoList);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Given this code, I have the following questions:

1. If someone unsubscribes from the observable returned from this method (after a previous subscription), is that operation thread-safe? So are my 'isUnsubscribed()' checks correct in this sense, regardless of scheduling?
2. Is there a cleaner way with less boilerplate code to check for unsubscribed states than what I'm using here? I couldn't find anything in the framework. I thought SafeSubscriber solves the issue of not forwarding events when the subscriber is unsubscribed, but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is that operation thread-safe?

Yes. You are receiving an rx.Subscriber which (eventually) checks against a volatile boolean that is set to true when the subscriber's subscription is unsubscribed.

> cleaner way with less boilerplate code to check for unsubscribed states

The `SyncOnSubscribe` and the `AsyncOnSubscribe` (available as an `@Experimental` api as of release 1.0.15) was created for this use case. They function as a safe alternative to calling `Observable.create`. Here is a (contrived) example of the synchronous case.

```
public static class FooState {
    public Integer next() {
        return 1;
    }
    public void shutdown() {

    }
    public FooState nextState() {
        return new FooState();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OnSubscribe<Integer> sos = SyncOnSubscribe.createStateful(FooState::new, 
            (state, o) -> {
                o.onNext(state.next());
                return state.nextState();
            }, 
            state -> state.shutdown() );
    Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.create(sos); 
}
```

Note that the `SyncOnSubscribe` next function is not allowed to call `observer.onNext` more than once per iteration nor can it call into that observer concurrently. Here are a couple of links to the `SyncOnSubscribe` [implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/observables/SyncOnSubscribe.java) and [tests](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/test/java/rx/observables/SyncOnSubscribeTest.java) on the head of the `1.x` branch. It's primary usage is to simplify writing observables that iterate or parsing over data synchronously and onNext downstream but doing so in a framework that supports back-pressure and checks if unsubscribed. Essentially you would create a `next` function which would get invoked every time the downstream operators need a new data element onNexted. Your next function can call onNext either 0 or 1 time.

The `AsyncOnSubscribe` is designed to play nicely with back pressure for observable sources that operate asynchronously (such as off-box calls). The arguments to your next function include the request count and your provided observable should provide an observable that fulfills data up to that requested amount. An example of this behavior would be paginated queries from an external datasource.

Previously it was a safe practice to transform your `OnSubscribe` to an `Iterable` and use `Observable.from(Iterable)`. This implementation gets an iterator and checks `subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` for you.

Comment: Thanks, you actually answered another question of mine regarding the creation of 'custom' observables with proper backpressure support! I checked out SyncSubscriber and it looks really good. In many cases I'd see converting an operation into an Iterable a bit awkward semantically, but it's still good to know that we can get easy backpressure-support that way. I see though that this class is still marked as @Experimental, when do you think it can be considered production-ready roughly?

Comment: Good to hear! The next step is to get it into a release (which should be coming up soon in 1.0.15). After that, generally it will promote into `@Beta` status or directly into public status as we gain confidence.